# How does exponent work in complex data structure in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I was exploring complex data structure in python. I have done addition, subtraction, multiplication and division between two complex value in python IDLE. All of them makes sense but when I tried to exponent a complex value something strange came up. I have no idea how that happened! Can anyone explain to me what's going under the hood?

I was trying to understand the following code:

```
>>> w = complex(2, -3)
>>> v = complex(5)
>>> w ** v
(122+597j)
```

So, I was wondering how `w ** v` evaluates to `(122+597j)`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you got is mathematically correct: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2-3i)%5E5

If you know how to multiply complex numbers, it is the same as `w*w*w*w*w`.

If you don't, here you go: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexMultiplication.html

Answer (score 1):

Recall that `complex(2,-3) = 2 - 3j`. With Newton's formula you get

```
 (a + b)**5 = a**5 + 5 a**4 b + 10 a**3 b**2 + 
              10 a**2 b**3 + 5 a b**4 + b**5
```

Applying Newton's formula to our case you get

```
  (2 - 3j) ** 5 = 
      2 ** 5 - 5 * 2**4 * 3j - 
      10 * 2**3 * 3**2 + 
      10 * 2**2 * 3**3 j +
      5 * 2 * 3**4 - 3**5 j =
      (2 ** 5 - 10 * 2**3 * 3**2 + 5 * 2 * 3**4) +
      (- 5 * 2**4 *3  + 10 * 2**2 * 3**3 - 3**5)j =
      122 + 597j
```